# What are logo ideas for money.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, top-7, design

Money should be nearing the end of its beta, so what should the logo be for Money?

Comment: What as the basically money logo?  Anyone have a link?

Comment: Related: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/185

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the site when it was Basically Money:  http://i.imgur.com/8IPJI.png

Comment: Is this also the question of what the favicon should be? Because that is often related to the logo.

Answer (score 7):

I'm kinda partial to whiskey and nickels.  Seriously though, since money has international followers it doesn't make sense to use the US dollar sign or any other currency sign.  It also doesn't make sense to use green colors predominantly in the design just because that is the color of money in the US.

Since government currencies come and go, I would prefer to incorporate the most predominant form of money for the last 5,000 years: gold and silver.

Comment: Definitely agree that green money (USD) should not be the dominant theme.

Comment: I suggest that if a few different currency symbols are used, it might be OK for the dollar sign ($) to be one of them :-)  But yes, I agree, no sense in having a U.S.-only flavor for a site that is broader than that.

Comment: @Alex B:  The US is not the only country that uses `$`!  Incl CAD, USD, NZD, AUD, MXN (peso)

Answer (score 5):

Probably some icon displaying coins and paper banknotes. And maybe added to that some chart charts (symbolizing stock, etc. investment). Maybe a piggy bank too?

I would try to avoid going to $$ signs - I know it's recognizable and most of the topics would end up related to dollars and US matters anyway, but if we could have something more generic it'd be nice.

Comment: I like the charts idea.

Comment: How about a blend of $ £ € ?

Comment: i love the piggy bank idea

Comment: @Chris - What about the Canadian dollar? or the Australian dollar? What if the Chinese allow the yuan to trade on currency markets?  It would instantly become one of the major currencies of the world.  I think it will be challenging to pick the right government currencies.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @Muro There's no saying we'd be picking the "right" currencies.  Just a handful of representative ones.  That's all.  BTW, the Canadian dollar is also represented by the dollar sign ($).

Comment: @Chris - good point.

Comment: +1 for the piggy bank. And some gold and silver (and spices? `:)`)

Comment: @Chris: I think that using currency symbols, even the "major" ones, might be unwelcoming to those who don't use them on a daily basis. In fact, currencies become "major" because the countries that use them are rich and a majority of their people are financially literate. I think that those who stand to benefit the most from this site are those who want to make the most of their low-valued currency, and therefore help their country grow by becoming financially literate themselves.

Comment: +1 for the piggy bank. I believe it's recognizable, not US-centric, and emphasizes the "personal" in "personal finance".

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: Copyright issues aside this one made me smile.  I've met Don Rosa in person and have a signed Scrooge McDuck.  "Work smarter, not harder." ;)

Answer (score 4):

The logo for Money should be a a large, green "dollar sign":

## $

[Although some say](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/what-are-logo-ideas-for-money-stackexchange-com/187#187) the above sign isn't international enough, it's definitely internationally recognizable.  In addition that same symbol not only used in the USA.  It is *also* used in Canada and Australia + NZ.  That's 2 entire continents!

Interestingly, the [$ sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign) has a Spanish origin (originally called the *peso sign*)

Comment: I disagree with the dollar sign. Yes, it is internationally recognizable, but the site isn't just for those 2 entire continents. I won't write my argument again here. See my comment in [this answer](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/184/what-are-logo-ideas-for-money-stackexchange-com/191#191)

Answer (score 3):

Well, this site is about finance, since we are trying to optimize our financial situations, how about graphs and charts? and maybe even place a symbol of some commodities in foreground. 
 [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of moneybags, but I think there are a lot of international users.  Maybe a big bag of coins instead of $ signs on the bags.  Or maybe a Pot of Gold at the end of the rainbow to symbolize the dream this site helps promote.

Comment: I'd hope the site helps people save money and invest, not look for it at the end of the rainbow ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about very old currency?  I linked to persian coins, but anything would do

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_daric

Another brainstorm (that I like less) would be to incorporate modern currency symbols and the old coins together.

Comment: The problem I see with old currency is that this site is about ways to handle your money now, with current theories, ideas, and best practices.

Comment: Some of the best ideas are pretty old.

Comment: cowries or gold bullions

Answer (score 1):

Cowries used to be the near-international currency for many years, some people in some rural areas still use them. so cowries for me.

Answer (score 1):

What about a picture of a guy balancing his checkbook?  This emphasizes the "personal finance" part of "personal finance and money."

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea and I don't have any picture ready to show this but here goes:
A picture of a hand shake (symbolizes communication between people). Then a glowing bulb above the handshake which is made up of a currency note instead of transparent glass..(symbolizes ideas that are generated as a result of information exchange between people).

Answer (score 0):

When I think of a design for this site, I tend to think of something that is reminiscent of a brokerage website or retirement site - clean, crisp, straight vertical and horizontal lines, and lots of white with one or two other colors in varying shades.

That said, I am somewhat partial to the idea of [moneybags](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=m0c&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&biw=1272&bih=764&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=moneybags&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) in the logo marked with different major currency symbols.  There's nothing about them that's clean and crisp, but I think it conveys the idea that getting good information and advice here will help you get and keep a bit more money.

Comment: Should we start a new question for just design ideas?