# What will the site look like after beta?

Tags: discussion, site-information

When this site *does* come out of beta, what will the user interface look like? Is there any place we could get a preview of it or give input about what it should look like? Or do we just get to be pleasantly surprised when we log in one day to find it out of beta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be a post here in the meta soliciting ideas when Jin begins the process.

He will likely also post a preview soliciting input.

A post already exists [discussing ideas for a logo](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/what-are-logo-ideas-for-money-stackexchange-com).