# Can we get a new header design?

Tags: discussion

I just found this site a few days ago and *love* it. However--and forgive me if this is inappropriate--but the site header is really lacking, especially when compared to other SE sites like [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/). It looks like people were [talking about logos a few years ago](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/what-are-logo-ideas-for-money-stackexchange-com), but this must not have gone anywhere. Is there any way we can improve the black text on grey header?

Answer (score 2):

We're still technically "beta".  We will get a proper site design when we graduate.

Comment: Yep! It's part of the "graduation" process. Money is currently in an in-between phase -- it's not really a true beta anymore, but we're looking for certain specific indicators before it can graduate. That said: every day I feel like I see real improvement and positivity here :)

Comment: @Aarthi So can we be next?  ;-) I was surprised "Travel" beat us, with metrics at launch that match ours.

Comment: Well the evaluation parameters continue to be mystery ;)